# How to create a second migration in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

Whenever I the migrate command, only one table is created. Yet I have more than one migration php files for different tables. How can I fix this? Any help thanks in advance.

This is what I get in the terminal when I run 'php artisan migrate'

**Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2020_03_29_184109_create_users_table**

Comment: Does this happen in a new Lumen project?

Comment: I don't why it was so, but after using "php artisan migrate:fresh". It got fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you migrated before? if yes, the framework will only migrate what hasn't been migrated.

Do `php artisan migrate:fresh` to force migrations.

Comment: Thanks guys. It now works after "php artisan migrate:fresh"

Comment: Nice! Mark the question as answered.